# Flutter: Connectivity Widget Wrapper Provider error

Tags: flutter, dart

I've added ConnectivityWrapperWidget with my custom offlineWidget. I'm getting this error, while running the app

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this ConnectivityWidgetWrapper Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that ConnectivityWidgetWrapper is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

I don't get it. Can somebody explain, what is the issue

Comment: Do yo use routing like `Navigator.push(...` in your code? If so, you can check your current tree structure (Flutter Inspector > Show Debug Paint). It can show the Provider location and your child location. Usually the error message is because the route split from `MaterialApp` class and provider is not the child's ancestor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While addig ConnectivityWrapper, if using custom offlineWidget(), then it was necesaary to add ConnectivityAppWrapper as a parent of MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use builder instead of child, as your error suggests. If it doesn't help, show some code.